# cobertura maven plugin in build-section

Tags: maven, cobertura

i am new to maven and work through a given pom. i found a section about a cubertura-maven-plugin in the build section of the pom.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</plugin>
```

The question is wether this makes sense or not, since i expected this plugin to be configure in the reporting section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense if you want to use cobertura data outside `mvn site`. Tools like [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) use cobertura this way.

By binding this plugin to a goal of your choice, you can use cobertura to do things like fail a build if there is inadequate coverage. See `Configuring check` section in [this usage page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 1):

Go and check [its usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html). Such basic configuration, as you said, doesn't make sense and should be moved to `<reporting>` section. But in general, you may need to do some more advanced configuration and need it in `<build>` block.

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends on whether you are using Maven 3 or not. If you are then the `<reporting/>` tag is no longer necessary. On the other hand you have to add your plugins as `<reportPlugins/>` to the `maven-site-plugin` configuration section.

Maven 3 differences [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#New_Configuration_Maven_3_only_no_reports_configuration_inheritance).

On the other hand your actual configuration shows no trace of being part of the `maven-site-plugin` so my answer may be a bit off-topic...